# Modifying an image in php

Tags: php, image-manipulation, php-gd

I have an image which i used as a template in php script .I have to edit certain portions of that image and add some text,pictures on that image during runtime.Now the problem is the image is to be modified at a large(but predefined) number of locations ,so i would have to hard code a large number of coordinates in the script. Is there any tool that can help in achieving the same task. or any other alternative ??

Comment: I would suggest simply opening paint, and hovering your cursor over the points of the image which you need to use and then reading the coordinate data from there.

Answer (score 1):

if you already have a set of predefined location, and you are on php, you can use php's imagick [library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)